# integration by trig substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I solved the following integral by using trig substitution $(u = 3 sec \theta)$

$$
\int \frac{dx}{x^{2}+10x+16}=\int \frac{du}{u^2-9}
$$

and got the same result as in the textbook which looked for $\int \frac{du}{u^{2}-a^2}$. Below is the process and result given in the textbook.

$$
\int \frac{du}{u^2-9}=\frac{1}{6}\ln \left| \frac{u-3}{u+3} \right|=\frac{1}{6}\ln \left| \frac{x+2}{x+8} \right|
$$

If I let $f(u) = \frac{1}{u^2-9}$, I am confused when using $u = 3 sec \theta$ due to the domain of $f(u)$ and the range of $3sec \theta$ : 
$$
3 \left| \sec\theta \right|\geq3
$$
but the domain of $f(u)$ is $[(-\infty, -3)\cup(-3, 3)\cup(3,\infty)]$.

In this case, how should I interpret the answer $\frac{1}{6}\ln \left| \frac{x+2}{x+8} \right|$?

I mean, I don't think I can use the answer if I want to solve definite integrals like below:

$$
\int_{-5}^{-3} \frac{dx}{x^2+10x+16}
$$
or 
$$
\int_{0}^{2} \frac{du}{u^2-9}.
$$

Is my guess right?

Comment: As shown below, partial fractions is an easier technique to use here; but the question you're asking is a good one. The substitution $u=3\sec\theta$ will give you the correct answer, even if you apply it to a definite integral with limits in $(-3,3)$; but as you point out, it would be more correct to write the integral as $-\int\frac{du}{9-u^2}$ and then use $u=3\sin\theta$ in that case.

Comment: @user84413 Whoa, thanks, in particular, for the comment about $-\int\frac{du}{9-u^2}$. But as I wrote below, the example seems to me to violate the theorem for integration by substitution (http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Integration_by_Substitution), so I still wonder how the substitution $u=3\sec\theta$ can lead to the correct answer.

Comment: Good question.  Letting $u=3\sec\theta$ in the integral gives the solution $\frac{1}{3}\ln|\frac{u-3}{\sqrt{u^2-9}}|+C$, which is not valid on $(-3,3)$, as you point out.  When you simplify algebraically to get $\frac{1}{6}\ln|\frac{u-3}{u+3}|+C$, though, you get an antiderivative which is valid on $(-3,3)$ in addition to $(-\infty,-3)$ and $(3,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be what you want, but do you notice the following?

$$\begin{align}\int\frac{1}{x^2+10x+16}&=\int\frac{1}{(x+5)^2-9}dx\\&=\int\frac{1}{u^2-9}du\\&=\frac 16\int\left(\frac{1}{u-3}-\frac{1}{u+3}\right)du\\&=\frac 16(\ln|u-3|-\ln|u+3|)+C\\&=\frac 16\ln\left|\frac{u-3}{u+3}\right|+C\end{align}$$

Here, I set $x+5=u.$

I think you don't need to use $u=3\sec\theta$.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're right. But the example was included in the section for trig substitution, so I didn't even think about applying partial fraction.

Comment: I was confused a lot since it seems to violate the theorem for integration by substitution, if I use $u=3\sec\theta$ for, say, $\int_{0}^{2} \frac{du}{u^2-9}$. But yes, as you said, now I think I don't need to struggle on with trig sub. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome!